# R: Reuse length

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a data frame, in which I want to find the reuse lengh of (x,y). Can someone suggest me the quickest method to analyze it. For example:

```
df <- data.frame(
  time=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6),
  x=c(1,4,2,1,6,1,4), 
  y=c(2,5,3,2,7,2,5)
)
```

I want average or median of the re-occurence of the same (x,y)/

Here, (1,2) repeats at time 0, 3, 5. So average = ((3-0) + (5-3))/2 = 2.5
And average for (4,5) is 5.

So, overall average is 3.75.

Can someone suggest how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this:

```
out <- aggregate(time ~ x + y, df, function(blah) {
  mean(diff(blah))
})
out
#   x y time
# 1 1 2  2.5
# 2 2 3  NaN
# 3 4 5  5.0
# 4 6 7  NaN
sum(out$time, na.rm=TRUE)
# [1] 7.5
```

---

A `data.table` approach:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df, key = "x,y")
DT[, mean(diff(time)), by = key(DT)][, sum(V1, na.rm=TRUE)]
# [1] 7.5
```

Comment: Better use `time ~ x*y`.

Comment: @Roland, thanks. Hadn't noticed the dependence on x and y as the ID vars. For `aggregate`, that generally means `x + y` not `x*y` for the formula method.

Comment: @Roland @Ananda Mahto What's the difference between `x + y` and `x*y`? In general I don't very well understand `time ~ x + y`. Any pointer will be very helpful

Comment: @RachitAgrawal, see the help file for `?aggregate` where it describes the `formula` method, and the `?formula` help file for details on the two variations.